# Results only appear after loop exit

Tags: javascript

My program searches based on a name parameter. It works, but the results don't appear until the user writes `Exit` to end the loop. Why don't the results show at the same moment that the user hits the enter key?

```
var list = ['Drake', 'Nail', 'Gerd', 'Ahmed', 'Omar', 'Joe', 'Hadi', 'Felex']; 
var search;

function printOut (IT) {
    document.write('<p>' + IT+'</p>');
}

while (true) {
    search = prompt(' if you want to know all the  student write list, if you want to exit the programm write exit, and if you want to search about a student persenolly, write his name!!');
    if (search === 'Exit') {
        break;
    } else if (search === 'list') {
        document.write(list.join(', '));
        break;
    } else {
        if (list.indexOf(search) > -1 ) {
            printOut('yes,' + search + ' in our class!!')
        } else {
            printOut('no,' + search + 'is not in our class!!')
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Because you have written code in a way that expects user to type `exit` and then only while exits. Also know that, JS is a single threaded language, so if while is running, it will freeze the screen

Comment: `why the results did not show in the same moment that the user hit the enter key` - because `document.write` is 20th century javascript - and browsers wont redraw the page until your script finishes

Comment: 20th century javascript ! lol

Comment: Jaromanda X my friend, another person wrote this code and it worked just fine with him , and when i wrote it  , it basically did not work with me.